How to control final shape of cloth inflation simulations
I'm trying to simulate the inflation of this box from its deflected state to its original shape. However, whenever I do so, the box becomes excessively “puffy” or short on the sides.
All the options I’ve tried (listed below) proved to be ineffective for me. Is there any way to control the final shape of the object with cloth/inflation simulations?

Animated or fixed walls from behind and in front resulted in the shape I wanted, but the simulation gets stuck at some point, with no movement at all and no reaction to any force field or collision (I suppose it’s because of the amount of pressure inside the box):

Settings of cloth simulations for object(box):

Blender file download link
Will be infinitely grateful to anyone who can help or give some piece of advice

What do you mean the simulation gets stuck at some point, with no reaction to force fields or collision? At what point? In your file I did not see something like that and adding a collision object myself towards the end the cloth reacted quite well: pillow.

Hello and welcome Bohdan Iva. Could you clarify the points being raised by Gordon? Then we can re-open your question.
